# Python - All combinations including brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-itertools

> For `u` unknown variables (e.g. a,b,c,d) and the symbols `+-*/`, find all possible equations of length `n`
>
> > An example being (`for u=2, n=5`):
> >
> > (a+b)/a

My current code can create a list of all possible equations, but without brackets

```
v = ["a", "b"]            #Variables
s = ["+", "-", "*", "-"]  #Symbols
n = 7                     #Amount of variables and symbols
a = []                    #Lists combined (find possible equations from)
for i in range(n):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        a.append(v)
    else:
        a.append(s)
equations = list(itertools.product(*a))
for each in equations:
    print("".join(each))
```

In conclusion, the code I have written doesn't contain all possibilities of an equation.

For example with `n=5 and 2 variables`, my code cannot find the possibility of `(a+b)*b`

With `n=7 and 4 variables`, it cannot find `(a+b)*(c+d)

**My main question:** How can I create some code that takes each possible equation and finds all possible brackets for it without duplicates

An example of a duplicate: `(a+b)*c` and `a*(b+c)`

Note: This is a duplicate because since every possible equation is being tested, at some point `a+b` will become `b+c`, so `*c` will become `*a`

Comment: This task requires to build them? not only count ?

Comment: Yes, to find all possible equations and save them to a list @Iluvatar

Comment: Your counting seems inconsistent. Your first example for n=3 is (a+b)/a, i.e. only variables are counted, but your later examples count both variables and operators, e.g. for n=5 you bring (a+b)*b. What exactly is the meaning of n?

Comment: @pentadecagon n includes variables and operators

Comment: You might want to look into building syntax trees, or ASTs for each equation.  That would take care of the bracket problem, because that information is stored in the structure of the tree instead.  For example, `(a+b)*c`  would be stored as something like `*(+(a, b), c)` (where `x(y, z)` means that node `x` has child nodes `y` and `z`).

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Could you please show me how this would work in a way which would solve the problem?

Comment: You mark `(a+b)*c` and `a*(b+c)` as examples for a duplicate, but that is only a duplicate if one has knowledge about the specific operators (i.e. whether they're commutative: `(a+b)/c` and `a/(b+c)` probably wouldn't be duplicates for you). With your bare list of operators this is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will work, but it does have a lot of expressions that will come to the same thing for example `x-x` or `x/x` with many different things in place of `x`.  However it avoids trivial duplicates due to associativity or commutativity.

Also the list of all possible expressions quickly gets insanely long.  For example with 4 variables and all expressions with 5 terms, you get 7845320 of them.  The use of generators will keep you from running out of memory, but not from it taking a very, very long time to run.

```
def all_expressions(size, variables):
    def _all_expressions(_size):
        if _size == 1:
            for variable in variables:
                yield (variable, '')
        else:
            for subsize in range(1, _size//2 + 1):
                for expr1, type1 in _all_expressions(subsize):
                    for expr2, type2 in _all_expressions(_size - subsize):
                        if subsize < _size - subsize or expr1 <= expr2:
                            if type1 == '+':
                                if type2 != '+':
                                    yield ("({} + {})".format(expr2, expr1), '+')
                            else:
                                yield ("({} + {})".format(expr1, expr2), '+')
                            if type1 == '*':
                                if type2 != '*':
                                    yield ("({} * {})".format(expr2, expr1), '*')
                            else:
                                yield ("({} * {})".format(expr1, expr2), '*')
                        if type1 != '*':
                            yield ("({} / {})".format(expr1, expr2), '/')
                        if type1 != '+':
                            yield ("({} - {})".format(expr1, expr2), '-')
                        if subsize < _size - subsize:
                            if type2 != '*':
                                yield ("({} / {})".format(expr2, expr1), '/')
                            if type2 != '+':
                                yield ("({} - {})".format(expr2, expr1), '-')
    for expr, t in _all_expressions(size):
        yield expr

for expr in all_expressions(3, ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    print(expr)
```

Comment: Great answer! You just need to add size to all_expressions when it's called at the end

Comment: Is there a way to remove duplicates such as `((b * b) / b)` being repeated twice?

Comment: All duplicates (if it helps), (only shows 2nd+ repetition):
`((b * b) / b)`, 
`(b / (b / b))`, 
`((b / b) / b)`, 
`(b - (b - b))`, 
`((b - b) - b)`, 
`((b + b) / b)`, 
`((b + b) - b)`, 
`(b / (b + b))`, 
`(b - (b + b))`, 
`((b * b) / b)`, 
`((b * b) - b)`, 
`(b / (b * b))`, 
`(b - (b * b))`, 
`((b / b) * b)`, 
`((b / b) / b)`, 
`((b / b) - b)`, 
`(b / (b / b))`, 
`(b - (b / b))`, 
`((b - b) + b)`, 
`((b - b) * b)`, 
`((b - b) / b)`, 
`((b - b) - b)`, 
`(b - (b - b))`

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld I just got rid of a lot of duplicates.  It did require some tweaks to associativity/commutativity logic.

Comment: btilly, what is `<>` supposed to be? Doesn't work for me!

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld My apologies for the python 2ism.  It is equivalent to !=.

Comment: No worries. Also, it says error line 7 float can't be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld Use `//` instead of `/`.  Again a Python 2ism.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Still around 122 out of the 216 equations are duplicates though apparently! Example: `(b+(b/b)) = (b*(b/b))`. Is there a way to remove these duplicates?

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld Hmm...the latest logic change squashes those.  I just need to not swap order when I'll find the other order in a different way.

Comment: That removes quite a few, how about `((b*b)-b) = (b+(b/b))`? It's down to 65 duplicates now! Also the reason I really want to try and remove all duplicates is because I'll be getting some rather large lists

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld Those aren't duplicates!  But I can have logic to not have both `x + (y - z)` and `(x + y) - z`.  And ditto for `x * (y / z)` and `(x * y) / z`.  Still you'll get long lists, and that is just in the nature of things.  There simply are a lot of expressions out there.

Comment: My mistake, I copied the wrong equations. I meant: `((a+a)-a) = ((a*a)/a) = (a*(a/a)) = (a/(a/a))`

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld That is getting into deeper analysis.  I would personally tackle that with a probabilistic method and a completely different algorithm.  Basically assign random large primes to the variables, and do exact fractional arithmetic.  Any two expressions that come up with the same thing are presumed to be equal.  Also you get to eliminate things like `.../(a-a)`.  Not guaranteed right, but likely so.